# Can a polymer coated with antibodies have enough attraction to wrap around a virus?

Tags: molecular-biology, microbiology, virology, antibody

[image]

[Archived source for image](https://web.archive.org/web/20210525031811/https://www.dw.com/en/german-researchers-are-working-on-a-tissue-that-will-tell-you-whether-youve-got-the-flu/a-17030239)

Please ignore the signal release. Does anyone know if it’s possible for polymer to wrap around a virus?

Comment: Please cite the sources of content like images in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can concentrate viruses and other objects of interest onto beads using antibody conjugated beads (such as [these ones](https://international.neb.com/products/s1431-goat-anti-mouse-igg-magnetic-beads) from New England Biolabs - I have no affiliation to any company linked in this post, but do occasionally use their products).  This is a process called [immuno-precipitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunoprecipitation) and has been around for a very long time.

This is also the principle behind [lateral flow assays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_flow_test), where an antigen (it can be a virus, they are available for e.g. [influenza](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/R24600) and [SARS-CoV-2](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanmic/article/PIIS2666-5247(21)00143-9/fulltext)) is suspended and placed onto the strip, where it crosses an antibody panel and binds to it. This then travels with the liquid front to a second antibody that detects the first and causes a signal of some sort to be released.